# Random shapes to disappear after a delay in powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

I have a lot of squares that will hide a picture behind them.

I will repeat this process in many slides in a ppt, That's why I want it to be random.

I am new to macros and don't understand them that well.

Is there a way to make a random square disappear and then after 2 seconds, another random square disappears, and so on? Until I stop it or all squares have disappeared.

Thank you in advance.

I have this code that makes the square disappear when clicked that I got from google.

```
Sub triggerMe()
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim oeff As Effect
On Error Resume Next
Set oshp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
If Not oshp Is Nothing Then
    Set osld = oshp.Parent
    Set oeff = osld.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add.AddEffect(oshp, msoAnimEffectFade, , msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick)
    With oeff
        .Timing.TriggerShape = oshp
        .Exit = True
    End With
End If
```

End Sub

This is a screenshot of the slide:

[image: Slide]

Here is the ppt link

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1SHJmcg4IaHsBaiqwJJZktXQQCjUKMq7a/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107891975751630303148&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this block of code works. It was a lot more complicated than I thought.

```
Sub Dala()
currentslide = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex
    
    Dim slideShapes As shapes
    Dim slideShape As Shape
    Dim osld As Slide
    Dim oshp As Shape
    Dim oeff As Effect
    
    'Get shapes for the slide
    Set slideShapes = ActivePresentation.Slides(currentslide).shapes
    
    Dim MyListOfNumbers(0 To 500) As Integer
    MyListOfNumbers(0) = 0
    Dim r As Variant
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim exist As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    
    
     
    For Each slideShape In slideShapes
        
        
        x = Random(slideShapes.Count)
        'So that it does not double animate the same square again
        For Each r In MyListOfNumbers
            If r = x Then
                exist = True
            End If
        Next r
        
        'Animates and add it to the array
        If exist = False Then
            MyListOfNumbers(i) = x
            Set oshp = slideShapes(x)
            Set osld = oshp.Parent
            On Error Resume Next
            Set oshp = oshp
            If Not oshp Is Nothing Then
                Set osld = oshp.Parent
                Set oeff = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(oshp, msoAnimEffectFade, , msoAnimTriggerAfterPrevious)
                    With oeff
                    .Timing.TriggerDelayTime = 1
                    .Exit = True
                    End With
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End If
        exist = False
    Next slideShape
End Sub


Function Random(High As Integer) As Integer
'Generates a random number less than or equal to
'the value passed in High
Randomize
Random = Int((High * Rnd) + 1)
End Function
```